# Why do view objects of the destination ViewController default to nil in prepareForSegue?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, segue

I was wondering if someone could explain why the outlets that are view objects of the destination ViewController in the prepareForSegue() function are set to nil.  I can only guess that it means that at the time PrepareForView is called, these objects are not created yet.  Wouldn't it make sense though that by the time you have your destination ViewController object, you'd have the view object outlets associated with it initialized as well?  I also know it's probably not good practice to directly modify the values of another ViewController's view, but I just want to understand the inner workings of Swift 3 better.  Thanks!

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ItemController"
    {
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row
        if let itemStruct = itemList[indexPath!] as ItemStruct?
        {
            let correspondingItemController : ItemController = segue.destination as! ItemController

            if let textView = correspondingItemController.textView
            {
                print("This is not nil!")  //this will NOT get hit.  Why is this still nil??
            }

            correspondingItemController.itemStruct = itemStruct
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: answer is: _at the time `prepare(for segue` is called, these objects are not created yet_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said at the time of `prepareForSegue` outlet objects are not yet created. ViewController loads/creates its view when the `view` property is accessed. When  `prepareForSegue` is being called your destination view controller is intantiated but its `view` is yet to be loaded. You can force controller to load its view from prepareForSegue by accessing `view` property.

```
let correspondingItemController : ItemController = segue.destination as! ItemController
let _ = correspondingItemController.view   // Forces controller to load its view.
```

Now you can access your outlets, but its not recommended. A good approach would be create variable in destination controller, set its value from `prepareForSegue`

```
// prepareForSegue
correspondingItemController.name = "something"

// Destination controller
var name:String

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
   textView.text = name
}
```

Comment: Anil, yeah the approach you suggest is what I'd been doing.  Good to know you can force the view as well.  Thanks!